# Flutter Gird View - Square items

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, gridview, flutter-layout

I have created a grid view with GridView.count, with 3 items per row. The issue is the items are rectangular in shape while I want to make them square

Here's the code:

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
    child: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      childAspectRatio: 1,
      children: categories
          .map((e) => Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
                child: Card(
                  color: e.color,
                  elevation: 2,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      side: BorderSide(color: e.borderColor, width: 1.5)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(e.name,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 14,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    ),
  )
```

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Padding` around the `Card` and specify the spacing between the elements in your `GridView` using:

- `mainAxisSpacing`
- `crossAxisSpacing`

Answer (score 1):

You have given a horizontal padding of 6 here which gave an extra space around the widget making the square grid look like a rectangle.

```dart
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
```

add vertical padding too, so its equally padded on all sides

```dart
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 6),
```